# ORA-01722: invalid number when using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entity

I have an entity Job as below.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Immutable
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Table(name = "JOB")
public class Job extends BaseEntity implements IEntity, IDto {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "JOB_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "PRINT_JOB_ID", length = 30)
  private String printJobId;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "PRINT_JOB_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Set<PrintFile> printFileInfos = new HashSet<PrintFile>();
}
```

I also have another entity PrintFile.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Immutable
@Table(name = "PRINT_FILE")
public class PrintFile implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "FILE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
  private String fileId;

  @Column(name = "PRINT_JOB_ID", nullable = false, length = 30)
  private String printJobId;
}
```

Here are my tables.

```
Job

JOB_ID                     NOT NULL NUMBER 
PRINT_JOB_ID                        VARCHAR2(30)  

Print_File

PRINT_JOB_ID               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)  
FILE_ID                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
```

When trying fetch Job data using Sprint boot rest API, I'm getting `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number` error. All the dataype mapping seems to be correct, what else could have gone wrong ?

EDIT:

The Job entity fetches without any issues when I get rid of the join. i.e, the entire declaration of printFileInfos in Job entity. This makes me think the issue is either with the join or in PrintFile entity.

Comment: Turn on Hibernate SQL logging and check what query exactly is being issued. Also, what is your BaseEntity? If it is also mapped, the problem might be there.

Comment: @ILyaCyclone There aren't any queries issued in the logs. The error seems to be thrown prior to that. BaseEntity just has serialVersionUID declared, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to try below given code. After adding referencedColumnName attribute, it worked for me.

```
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "PRINT_JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRINT_JOB_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Set<PrintFile> printFileInfos = new HashSet<PrintFile>();
```